# Native Image Size is atleast twice the actual Jar size

Tags: spring-boot, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

Have built a `native-image` using `Spring Boot 3.0.1` and `GraalVM 22.3.0`. The built `native-image` size is atleast twice as that of the original application jar.

I'm with the understanding if unused classes are removed as part of the native-image build process, it should be lesser in size.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look closer to the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/native-image.html#native-image.introducing-graalvm-native-images) you will understand

> A GraalVM Native Image is a complete, platform-specific executable.
> **You do not need to ship a Java Virtual Machine in order to run a
> native image.**

So a GraalVm Native Image, contains both the application and the dependencies needed for this container to execute. Without Native image you normally had as `JAR` just the application and the embedded tomcat. You did not had inside this `JAR` the `JRE` or `JDK`, required to run the `JAR` file.

The above could also be verified from [graalVm](https://www.graalvm.org/latest/reference-manual/native-image/).

> Native Image is a technology to compile Java code ahead-of-time to a
> binary – a native executable. **A native executable includes** only the
> code required at run time, that is the application classes,
> standard-library classes, **the language runtime, and statically-linked
> native code from the JDK.**

The language runntime in case for `java` and `jdk` are normally between 100mb - 200mb. The graalVm probably reduces this size but not in huge size. So the native executable image is increased by even 1 hundred Mbs just from that.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a small table comparing a hello world example with minimal spring boot based apps.

| Description | Original Jar Size | Executable (Fat) Jar Size | Native Image Size | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BellSoft HelloWorld Example | 775B | - | 11M | [Instructions](https://bell-sw.com/blog/spring-boot-with-graalvm-native-image-performance-compatibility-migration/#mcetoc_1gnk7mjie3g%5BInstructions%5D) |
| Minimal spring boot application | 45K | 9.0M | 35M | spring-boot-starter |
| Minimal spring boot application with embedded tomcat | 116K | 18M | 63M | spring-boot-starter-web |
| Small Real World Application | 227K | 37M | 87M | moderate number of dependencies |

```
openjdk version "19.0.1" 2022-10-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment GraalVM CE 22.3.0 (build 19.0.1+10-jvmci-22.3-b08)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM GraalVM CE 22.3.0 (build 19.0.1+10-jvmci-22.3-b08, mixed mode, sharing)
```